# laravel Change Router Dynamic Localization

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to Localization. If there are buttons A and B.
The country code is "KO" when you click the A button.
If you click B button, I want to set it as "JA" country code.

For example, www.neiter.site/ko/commonity

I want to change it dynamic. 
Please show me how.

Wherever I go, I want to change only the part of the country code URL from "ko" to "ja." Of course the opposite is possible.

Comment: `/{loc}/commonity` - and process it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{loc}/commonity', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
})
```

[Read More ..](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization)